# Auto link word on a page using javascript

Tags: javascript

The code below is meant to put links in words, but it works only with english words, I would like it to work with arabic words too

**The code**

```
    <script>
// <![CDATA[
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var links = {
      "مغامرات": "https://www.example.com/search/label/%D9%85%D8%BA%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA",
      "East": "https://www.example.com/search/label/%D8%AE%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%84",
   }
   
   var bodi = document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(script)");
   for(var x=0; x<bodi.length; x++){
      var html = bodi[x].innerHTML;
      for(var i in links){
         var re = new RegExp("([\\s|&nbsp;]"+i+"(?:(?=[,<.\\s])))", "gi");
         var matches = html.match(re);
         if(matches){
            matches = html.match(re)[0].trim();
            html = html.replace(re, function(a){
               return ' <a href="'+links[i]+'">'+a.match(/[A-zÀ-ú]+/)[0].trim()+'</a>';
            });
         }
      }
      bodi[x].innerHTML = html;
   }
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Let me change the way that you choose to a better and more understandable one.*

In this example we made a simple function to **detect words** by a **dynamic RegEx** and **replace an anchor (a)** tag with link instead:

```js
function linkWords(elem,words,links) {
  // Using innerHTML to replace anchor links easier
  elem.innerHTML=elem.innerHTML.replace(
    // Make a (g:global, i:case insensitive) RegEx from joinig words by groups indicators
    // (!) Group indicators will pass to the function arguments as their index 
    RegExp('('+words.join(')|(')+')','gi'),
      // This function will get arguments like this:
      // [match,parenthesized capture group...,offset,string]
      function(){
        // So we ignore the first one and the last two
        for (var i=1;i<arguments.length-2;i++)
          // If we found not undefined group
          if (arguments[i])
            // We return the captured match mixed with the anchor tag using the same index of the link
            return '<a href="'+links[i-1]+'">'+arguments[0]+'</a>';
      }
  );
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", linkWords(document.body,
  ["كلمة","word"],
  ["https://www.example.com/search/%D9%83%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A9","https://www.example.com/search/word"]
 ));
```

```html
<div>Hi! this is a word and it have to be linked.</div>
<div dir="rtl">السلام علیکم! هذه كلمة ويجب ربطها.</div>
```

For understanding well what happen up there, you can read more about these resources:

- [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [String.prototype.replace() - Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)
- [Standard built-in objects > RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
- [Regular expressions > Groups and ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges)

**Important notes:** That function is just a first step for understanding and used an `experimental method`, not a standard (trust-able) method, because of these possibilities:

1. Special reserved character in RegEx are not escaped
2. Using `innerHTML` without special cares may not get the HTML Encode characters
3. We have some same characters in Arabic/Persian that look same but actually different Unicode, so we have to detect them as same characters. Example: `ي ى ی` *Ya* - `4 ٤ ۴` *Numbers* etc...
4. It can not detect difference between readable texts [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or attributes or non-readable tags texts like `<style>` or `<script>`
5. Needing many `Pre-fix` & `Post-Fix` for inputs to don't make mistakes. Example; duplicates in inputs can make mess like: ['win','window'] or not detecting already linked words

Also usually these kind of acts should be Server-side to avoid many Client-side possible mistakes.

**So** if you want to keep doing it in Client-side (Front-End):

- Use libraries, like: [linkify](https://linkify.js.org/) - https://github.com/Hypercontext/linkifyjs
- Improve the example by researching more about the resources

---

##### Update

If we want to solve the problem of **avoiding linking of already linked words**, And we also want to look at the issue in a simplistic way, we can add a [Negative Look-ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in our pattern for improving the RegEx.

Live example, for understanding how it work:
https://regexr.com/6c00r

Visualized pattern:
[image: Visualized pattern]
https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=ig&re=(%3F!%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3C%5C%2Fa%3E)(%3F%3A(word)%7C(%D9%83%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A9))

```js
function linkWords(elem, words, links) {
    elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(
        // Improved RegEx by adding Negative lookahead that check not between <a>
        RegExp('(?![^>]*</a>)(?:(' + words.join(')|(') + '))', 'gi'),
        function() {
            for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length - 2; i++)
                if (arguments[i])
                    return '<a href="' + links[i - 1] + '">' + arguments[0] + '</a>';
        }
    );
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", linkWords(
    document.querySelector('.me'), // <---- First argument choose the target element
    ["كلمة", "word"], // Array of the targeted words
    ["https://www.example.com/search/%D9%83%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A9", "https://www.example.com/search/word"] // Array of the words links
));
```

```css
.me {background: #efefef;}
a {text-decoration: underline;}
```

```html
<div class="me">
  <div>Hi! this is a word and it have to be linked.</div>
  <div dir="rtl">السلام علیکم! هذه كلمة ويجب ربطها.</div>
  <div>Not this <a>word</a> that already is inside an anchor tag. But still this WORD.</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>Another element: word word word</div>
```

Explaining the RegEx:

- `(?![^>]*<\/a>)` the `Negative Lookahed` `(?!...)` will check:

  - If next group `(?:...)` is NOT:

    - Start with any `[^>]` (ANY, NOT finished tag character)

      - As much as `*`

        - Find a closed anchor `</a>`
- Then check if the `Non-Capturing group` `(?:...)` (to don't change the index of other groups)

  - Have any of this `(word)` (Group number 1)
  - Or `|`
  - This `(کلمه)` (Group number 2)
  - Or more `(word1)|(word2)|(word3)|...`
- When you took the word `/.../gi`:

  - `g` (Global) Go next for more
  - `i` (Ignore Case) Be case insensitive (A=a)

Comment: you are the best man :)

Comment: but just, anyway to make it dont work on words which already linked ?

Comment: and can I change the target from "body" to the child p in class ".post-body"

Comment: @RyυĸKυяαɪ you're welcome, i will update by trying to keep it simple, Because i assumed this was a first step and you would try to finish it yourself with more research and effort. Best regards.